# awk (or sed/python) skipping rows to renumber a column

Tags: python, awk, sed

I need help renumbering elements. I have an input file like the small sample below (nodes and elements could be in the 1000's).  I need a code that skips down past all the nodes and starts with the first element, and at that point I need to add an integer to all the elements. IE: element 658 = 1658, 659=1659, etc.... 
Everything needs to be outputted into a new file, the only differences is the renumbering of the elements. 
I tried doing this with the awk command, code below, cannot quite get it. Can someone help? Is python or sed better? Thanks

```
*NODE, NSET=Nvolc
   1,6.106226635438e-16,0.000000000000e+00,1.000000000000e+01
   2,6.106226635438e-16,0.000000000000e+00,-1.000000000000e+01
   3,5.481726184087e-16,0.000000000000e+00,9.000000000000e+00
*ELEMENT, TYPE=C3D4, ELSET=Evolc
   658,    58,   193,   148,   113 
   659,   154,    81,   215,   119 
   660,   228,    58,   148,    36 
   661,     7,   131,   146,   302
```

Code:

```
    awk 'NR==1{print}' test.msh > test2.msh | nawk -v number=500 'NR <= 2 { next } BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {$1=number;print;number++;print}' test.msh > test2.msh
```

Comment: [edit] your question to include the expected output given your posted sample input.

Comment: If my answer was helpful, please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use an [address range](https://adayinthelifeof.nl/2010/12/06/sed-simple-pattern-address-usage/) in `sed` to do this:

```
sed '/ELEMENT/,$s/^   \([0-9]\)/   1\1/' test.msh
```

The range `/ELEMENT/,$` means to search from the first occurrence of "ELEMENT" until the end of the file. The rest is just a simple [substitution](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-1) with [back reference](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-8) that assumes your whitespace is consistent.

Re-reading your question, you aren't clear if you want to change all the numbers, or just the first one on each line. If you want to replace all of them, this should work:

```
sed '/ELEMENT/,$s/ \([0-9]\)/ 1\1/g' test.msh
```

Answer (score 1):

```
awk digit=1 \
    'adjust    { $1 = digit $1 } \
     /ELEMENT/ { adjust = 1 } \
               { print }'
```

If adjusting, concatenate `digit` to the first element.  Turn on adjusting when `ELEMENT` appears on a line.  Print everything.